# Condición para inserción de datos

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Amigos buenos días, adjunto el script de una consulta que estoy realizando

```
SELECT        otrnTransaction.ID_Trn AS IdDiarioTrans, otrnTransaction.AmountPur + otrnTransaction.AmountCentralRetailMarkup + otrnTransaction.AmountTaxes AS Monto
FROM            otrnTransaction
WHERE        (otrnTransaction.PostingDate = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate FROM prProperty))
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CONSULTA: Necesito insertar estos resultados en otra tabla pero bajo una condición, la tabla de destino tiene dos columnas CREDITO Y DEBITO, necesito insertar el monto si es positivo en DEBITO y si es negativo en el CREDITO.

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo? no sé si hay IF en SQL

Answer (score 1):

La fuente de la data, la funcion y la condicion en los comentarios explico cada una de ellas.

1. La Fuente la tabla otrnTransaction tomo el campo ID_Trn y filtramos la data usando un exists que es menos costoso que usar un igual que puesto que el igual que compara mientras que el exists es un buleano y no le importa la data
2. La Funcion. en la pregunta el manda la funcion de suma como el campo monto. esa funcion se puede hacer mas legible si la ponemos como una cross apply puesto que el procesamiento pasaria a la primera capa del query que es el from.
3. La Condicion. si el valor del monto es diferente del absoluto es negativo y si no es positivo y como esto es para un registro contable tengo que hacer el valor 0 y no null.

   ```
   insert into t_balances --tabla destino 
   (IdDiarioTrans, Debito, Credito) --campos especificos 

   SELECT 
   a.ID_Trn AS IdDiarioTrans, 
   case 
     when b.Monto = ABS(monto) then monto 
     else 0 
   end as debito, -- el abs te da el valor absoluto y siempre sera  positivo
   case 
     when b.Monto != ABS(monto) then monto 
     else 0 
   end as credito -- el abs te da el valor absoluto y siempre sera positivo
   FROM otrnTransaction as a -- el alias es mas facil de leer
   cross apply (values
                 (a.AmountPur + a.AmountCentralRetailMarkup + a.AmountTaxes)
            ) as b(monto)--la suma la es una funcion lineal y es mas  rapido y legible de esta manera
    --la condicion es mas rapida cuando evaluas booleano
   WHERE exists (select * from prProperty as c where a.PostingDate =   
   c.CurrentHotelDate)
   ```

Comment: Podrias explicar como llegaste a esta solución para que sea aceptada tu respuesta

Comment: perdon no entendi bien las reglas de stack es mi primera respuesta. pero aqui explico. el codigo esta compuesto por 3 partes la fuente de la data, la funcion y la condicion. en los comentarios explico cada una de ellas.

1. La Fuente. la tabla otrnTransaction. tomo el campo ID_Trn  y filtramos la data usando un exists que es menos costoso que usar un igual que puesto que el igual que compara mientras que el exists es un buleano y no le importa la data.

Comment: 2. La Funcion. en la pregunta el manda la funcion de suma como el campo monto. esa funcion se puede hacer mas legible si la ponemos como una cross apply puesto que el procesamiento pasaria a la primera capa del query que es el from.

3. La Condicion. si el valor del monto es diferente del absoluto es negativo y si no es positivo y como esto es para un registro contable tengo que hacer el valor 0 y no null.

Answer (score 0):

Existen if's pero son para variar el resultado que vas a insertar no para cambiar de campo.

Tienes dos opciones, hacer dos inserts distintos o bien hacer un script y para poder hacer lo que quieres.

Answer (score 0):

Pudes usar CASE:

```
SELECT IdDiarioTrans,
    CASE WHEN Monto >= 0 THEN Monto ELSE NULL END AS Credito,
    CASE WHEN Monto < 0 THEN Monto ELSE NULL END AS Debito
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT otrnTransaction.ID_Trn AS IdDiarioTrans, otrnTransaction.AmountPur + otrnTransaction.AmountCentralRetailMarkup + otrnTransaction.AmountTaxes AS Monto
        FROM otrnTransaction
        WHERE (otrnTransaction.PostingDate = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate FROM prProperty))
    ) T;
```

Para insertar los resultados:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (IdDiarioTrans, Credito, Debito)
SELECT IdDiarioTrans,
    CASE WHEN Monto >= 0 THEN Monto ELSE NULL END AS Credito,
    CASE WHEN Monto < 0 THEN Monto ELSE NULL END AS Debito
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT otrnTransaction.ID_Trn AS IdDiarioTrans, otrnTransaction.AmountPur + otrnTransaction.AmountCentralRetailMarkup + otrnTransaction.AmountTaxes AS Monto
        FROM otrnTransaction
        WHERE (otrnTransaction.PostingDate = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate FROM prProperty))
    ) T;
```

Comment: Creo que esta es la respuesta más acertada y la que funciona pero por el momento tengo este error:
The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Comment: El número de columnas en el INSERT debe ser igual al número de columnas en el SELECT.